# Disable collectstatic and paver when javascript or css changes in Openedx

Tags: javascript, css, openedx, collectstatic, paver

Can we disable collectstatic and paver when javascript or css changes in Openedx?

Because as a developer, we frequently change the javascript or css and would like to view the outcome directly from openedx platform. Currently if any javascript or css change requires to run collectstatic and paver, it will take as long as 15 mins to finish and see the result.

It really wastes a lot of time for developers.

Please enlight me how to disable them and once the javascript or css is changed on Linux hardisk, the end user browser will see the change effect immediately.

And meanwhile, any python (.py) file changes require to restart certain service to see the result. Is there a way that we do not need to restart the service, then we can see the result immediately?
for example, restart lms, cms services...

We would like to see the javascript and css changes immediately when we overwrite the existing files on the harddisk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Open edX [Tutor](https://docs.tutor.overhang.io/) release for Open edX developments. You may compile assets in real-time using Tutor's "[watchthemes](https://docs.tutor.overhang.io/tutorials/theming.html)" option.